# Beginning Scheme (LISP) dealing with lists and appending values

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I am trying to make a function that takes 2 numbers and will create a list using the first number as a starting number and the second number as the ending value while filling in the values between the starting and ending numbers.

For example:

User passes in 3 and 7:

the output should be  (3 4 5 6)

I was trying to do this and use recursion but I am struggling:

```
 (define (createlist start end)
   (if(= start end)
      '())
   (cons start '())
    (createlist (+ 1 start) end))
```

Comment: Use `cons` and work backwards -- build it up from the tail. Also, need to call the function again to make it recursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a repeating pattern found in the solution to this sort of problems where you have to build a list along the way using recursion. Let me illustrate the general steps, I'll let you fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (createlist start end)
  (if (= <???> <???>) ; the problem is solved when start and end are the same
      '()             ; lists end in null
      (cons <???>  ; if we are not done yet, we `cons` the current value of start
            (createlist <???> end)))) ; with the result of calling the recursion
            ; notice that start is one step closer to the end, so we increment it
```

The idea of the algorithm is that at each step we add the current `start` value to the list that is being built with `cons`, and increment `start` until it reaches `end`, at this point the recursion ends.

You should take a look at either [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) or [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), both books will teach you how to structure the solution for this kind of recursive problems over lists.

**UPDATE:**

Now that you've posted the code you've written so far, I can show you the right answer. Please be very careful with parenthesis [ the closing parenthesis of an `if` goes after the `else` part ] and white spaces [ `if(` is not the same as `if (` ], they matter a lot in Scheme. Also indent correctly your code, it'll help you find a lot of bugs:

```
(define (createlist start end)
  (if (= start end)
      '()
      (cons start
            (createlist (+ 1 start) end))))
```

Now you can see how the `<???>` get correctly filled.

Comment: where is it creating the list?

Comment: @cougar successive calls to `cons` create a list. for example this: `(cons 1 (cons 2 '()))` creates the list `'(1 2)`, notice that a list must end in `'()`, the null list.

Comment: ok that makes sense. And i am gonna want to increment start in the bottom code right?

Comment: That's right, you're on the right track to understand and solve it now!

Comment: i am trying to do (+ start 1) and i keep getting stuck in an endless loop.its like it isnt even saving the value

Comment: endless loops in recursion generally mean that there's a problem with the base condition, check the first pair of <???>'s

Comment: I added my most recent code i thin that base condition is correct though isnt it?

Comment: You have several parenthesis and whitespace problems :( look, you've tried hard enough so I'll give you a straight answer, see my updated solution

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions (without trying to give away the entire solution):

- use `cons` instead of `append`
- use indentation to show the structure of your program
- the `if` doesn't have an else value -- I suspect you meant for the last line to be it -- you'll have to rearrange the parenthesis.  Also, common style frowns upon `if(` and `list(` -- use `if (` and `list (` instead (note the spaces).  Example:

  ```
  (define (my-function a b c)
    (if (= a 3)   ;; note the space between if and (
        b         ;; the 'then' line
        c))       ;; the 'else' line
  ```
- if you're recursing, you'll have to call `createlist` from within its body.  Did you mean for the second `list` to be `createlist`?  Remember that it takes 2 parameters
- if you don't want infinite recursion, make sure to change the arguments so that they're closer to finishing.  In other words, you don't want to recurse with the same values of `start` and `end`.  Which one should you change, and in what way?

Comment: I was thinking i could just keep incrementing the start value

Comment: how could i use cons to add an item to the end of a list?

Comment: So, you have '(a b c) and you want to add 'd?  If you don't mind ending up with '((a b c) d), the answer is simple.  If you want '(a b c d) as a result, then the answer (once again) involves recursion.  So think about it a little bit and come back with a brand new question, illustrating your thinking ;)